# Django migration error can't adapt type UUID

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I've changed my model PK from this:

```
id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=make_key, max_length=32)
```

to this

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=TimeUUID, editable=False)
```

Where [TimeUUID is this function](https://github.com/Tamarabyte/TimeUUID). However, I get an error when running migrate below, why?

The DB has no data in I cleared all rows.
The function generates UUIDs that look like this:

```
00332873-d693-da82-720e-27dff1cf2a9b
00332873-d693-db36-dd92-eac7c082f13c
00332873-d693-dc0a-aef8-9fb752a3fb6c
```

i.e. `[32 bits timestamp high]-[16 bits timestamp mid]-[16 bits timestamp low]-[16 bits random]-[48 bits random]`

The DB is Postgres.

Error:

```
  File "/Users/user/Documents/app/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'TimeUUID'
```

Could it be that the Django UUID field does not accept UUIDs with bits in a different order?

Also tried:

```
def get_UUID():
    return TimeUUID()
```

Then

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, unique=True, default=get_UUID, editable=False)
```

Which still gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TimeUUID is a class. Calling it returns an instance of that class. Django has no idea what to do with that value, as there is no clue how it could be stored as a value in the database.

In order to use it, you'd need to convert it to a string. You could do that in a lambda:

```
id = models.UUIDField(
    primary_key=True, unique=True, default=lambda: str(TimeUUID()), editable=False)
```

Comment: for some reason you get ``Cannot serialize function: lambda`` with above.

Comment: I have updated my OP and tried to use ``get_UUID`` this is how in the past I have gotten around the lambda error above, but still get the same error can't adapt type 'TimeUUID'. I have also removed the tables and started again, this time it created but when trying to insert data in the admin I get the same error ``ProgrammingError at /admin/user/activity/add/
can't adapt type 'TimeUUID``

Comment: Your `get_UUID` function still needs to return the str, not the instance.

Comment: Thanks Daniel yep you are right. it was returning the class object. I added ``str()`` to the return on the function and it worked! Strange the lambda function did not work tho that is neat.